# Manga where the main character gets summoned to another world with three other people by a god

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

So the main character (MC) gets summoned with three other people (one boy and two girls) to another world, to save it from a demon lord, but as they were being summoned, the other male pushed the MC out of the summoning circle, which caused him to be sent to another place. The God saw what happened and gave the other male's skill to the MC.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[I Received Blessings Meant for 2 People From God](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/e7mlhdw/kami-sama-ni-kago-2-ninbun-moraimashita)***...?

> As he was being transferred to a different world with his classmates, Fubuki Amasaka was pushed out of the teleportation circle by his class bully, Yushin. When he woke up, he was alone and deep in a forest.
> However God, who had saw the entire thing and already warned them to stay in the circle, took Yushi's cheat skill away and gave it to Fubuki as punishment.
> Can Fubuki, who got two divine blessings, live in a different world safely?

A Japanese high school student is summoned to another world along with another male classmate and two girls. The other boy pushes the main character (MC) out of the teleportation circle, which causes him to arrive in another location, and a god punishes the other boy by transferring his skill to the MC, giving the MC two skills instead of one.

[image]

[image]